# Delphi - Passing variable pointer as string to another function

Tags: delphi, pointers, stream

I don't know if it is even possible, but what I need is to access (use and free) a TStream variable by it pointer, passed thought a string parameter to another function.

Here is a "not working" example of what I am trying to do:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo.Lines.SaveToStream(Stm);
    Stm.Position := 0;
    Memo.Clear;
    Edit.Text := IntToStr(Integer(@Stm));
  except
    Stm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PStm: ^TMemoryStream;
begin
  PStm := Pointer(StrToInt(Edit.Text));
  try
    Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(PStm^);  // <--- Access Violation
  finally
    PStm^.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks for any help to solve this!

Comment: You've already freed Stm before Button1Click finishes, so the "pointer" you've captured in Edit1.Text is stale by the time Button2Click executes.  You would get better help if you explain why you think that what you want to do is necessary.

Comment: @MartynA, Stm will be freed on Button1Click only if some exception occurs. I will use this in a complex application, with TCP communication, and belive me, I would not go this path if was not necessary...

Comment: Sorry, I misread your "except" for "finally".  But still, what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Let me try to explain... It is a TCP Client-Server application. They exchange strings and streams between then (server and client). When need to send a stream, I first send a string message, telling I will send stream next. At this point would be necessary to check what is the stream and generate it. But what I will do is to generate the stream and pass it pointer as a string...

Comment: @Paruba This is a recipe for disaster. I suggest you redesign a little to avoid this problem before the anti-patten becomes too entrenched in your application. What I suggest is: **1)** Take the stream's lifetime out of your producer (Button1) and consumer (Button2) and give it a longer life that would span both. **2)** Pass the stream instance into the producer and consumer. **3)** Both producer and consumer then just use the stream without worrying about its lifetime.

Comment: @CraigYoung, thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TStream is a reference type. Your `Stm` variable holds a pointer to the stream object instance. You want to pass this pointer value, not the address of the local variable. Here's the fixed code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo.Lines.SaveToStream(Stm);
    Stm.Position := 0;
    Memo.Clear;
    Edit.Text := IntToStr(Integer(Stm));
  except
    Stm.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stm := Pointer(StrToInt(Edit.Text));
  try
    Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(Stm);
  finally
    Stm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if there's no memory allocation on the heap between the end of `Button1Click` and the allocation of the stream in `Button2Click`, as it relies on the memory not changing to (hackishly) get the same stream again.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you. I understood and gave up using this method :)

Comment: @KenWhite, Heap allocations wouldn't cause any problems as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KenBourassa: Yes, it does. The stream is freed in `Button1Click`. `Button2Click` *assumes* that the memory at the pointer address is a `TMemoryStream`, and as long as no other allocation in the heap occurs that assumption might succeed. If a different object instance is allocated (even elsewhere) between the clicks, it is allocated from the heap, the assumption fails and the cast to a memory stream AVs.

Comment: @KenWhite, the stream is only freed in `Button1Click` if an exception occurs there. And then, the Edit.text won't be assigned anyway.

Comment: @KenBourassa: You're right. Missed the except. It's a bad idea in general to pass a memory address (pointer) around as a string and then convert it back to a numeric value and expect the contents to be the same at some later point.

Comment: Wow, didn't think this is even possible, well done! Ondrej

Comment: @KenWhite, I don't think it's a bad idea to pass an object with string, on the contrary, I think it's a very flexible way to pass/store information! It's just like `TComponent.Tag`, isn't it?

Comment: One note - we should use `NativeInt` instead of `Integer` in order to compatible with both 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: @EdwinYip: TComponent.Tag is an integer value. I don't get your point. I've never used TComponent.Tag to hold a pointer to a string, either. If you can pass it to somewhere that the pointer will still be valid, you don't need to pass it as a string, and if you're passing it somewhere that you can't directly pass that pointer as a pointer, the pointer is most likely not valid at the destination anyway.

Comment: @KenWhite, Re. "If you can pass ... the pointer ..., you don't need to pass it as a string", well, you can be that certain about the situations of other programs ;)

Comment: @EdwinYip: The situations of other programs doesn't make any difference. If you're passing pointers around when you could use an actual valid data type, you're leaving yourself open to bugs that can be difficult to track down. Delphi is a strongly typed language, and you should use that strong typing when you can so that the compiler can warn you when you're doing something foolish. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, Of course in most cases and when possible, we should use the exact type of the data. My point is that, there are rare cases you might need that trick (pass pointers as strings) to solve a special issue. There are no conflicts I guess :)